# Check buttons before and after active status button

Tags: php, html, button, smarty

I need to check the before and after active status in order to add a tick to the actions that have already been performed.

Currently, the actions are listed in button form, it checks to see the active status of the job and then gets the active action, all other actions are listed but not clickable.

```html
<div class="card card">
  <div class="card-title card-white-title">Booking Actions</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    {foreach from=$booking_actions item=action}
      <button data-price="{$booking.est_price}" value="{$booking.reference}" id="{$action.integra_status}" class="btn btn-booking-control {$action.integra_action}{if $action.enabled == false} disabled action-disabled-btn{else} btn-success{/if}{if $action.show_on_portal == 'NO'} hidden{/if}" {if $action.enabled != false}onclick="javascript:performButtonAction('{$action.integra_action}', '{$action.integra_status}', '{$booking.reference}', '{$action.stop_ref}',this)"{/if}>
        {if $action.enabled == true}
          {$action.description} {$action.applies_to_desc}
            {else}
              {$action.description} {$action.applies_to_desc}  <div class="pull-right"><div class="fas fa-check"/></div>
           {/if}
        </button>
     {/foreach}
   </div>
</div>
```

what I'm currently getting is the full list of actions, the active action that's clickable and all others have a tick.

I want to get actions before the current active to have a tick and ones after to not have one.
I know I need to check its position, I need something like a {while $action.enabled != true} but I'm not sure where I need to have it and how best to get it to work.....

[current outcome](https://ibb.co/Vqt1PW6)

[wanted outcome](https://ibb.co/swXCSqr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign and reassign variables in Smarty. In your case, you could set a `$showTick` variable to true initially, then set it to false as soon as you encounter the first enabled action. Here's a minimal working example:

```
{$showTick=true}
{foreach $actions as $action}
  {if $action.enabled}
    {$showTick=false}
  {/if}
  <button class="btn {if $action.enabled}btn-success{else}disabled{/if}">
    {$action.description}
    {if $showTick}
      ✓
    {/if}
  </button>
{/foreach}
```

[image: no ticks past the third item]

Comment: thank you so much, that works perfectly.
just the results I was after, I've only been using PHP, CI, Smartys for 6 months and although I'm getting most of my project sorted, this one I was getting in a muddle with. so thank you so much.